# Advanced Filters in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've been segmenting my full "referral" path to the "user defined value" using advanced filters.

[image: screen shot]

**I would like that data, which obvious is the form of an URL, to be clickable. Would even be better if it could open in a new window.**

Anyone know what I should feed the "user defined value" to get that behavior?

I've put up an image to better explain what I'm trying to do (sorry for the blur but it was the only think the client allowed). What I'm trying to do is put the yellow part (the full link path) as an external link so that I can click on it and just visit the site that brought the user here.

Any thoughts on how to do it?

[image: desired output]

Comment: Can you please state the reason of the downvote so that I can better understand/improve my question? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Web Analytics questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It may be a good fit at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

There are browser extensions that can offer this functionality. Chrome supports it natively (kind of) and there is an extension for Firefox.

http://www.snaphow.com/select-and-open-plain-text-non-linked-urls-in-firefox-like-chrome/

With both you need to select the text and right click then select open in new window.

Comment: thks for the answer, nevertheless it wont work on this scenario because Analytics cuts down the "visible" part of the link (the text) leaving the full link as a `title` element. Therefor you can never select the full link. Any one ideas? Thks!